# How do I stop strokes from increasing the measurements of an object?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, transform

When I draw a box that's 4x2. The transform panel usually confirms this measurement by showing W:4 (width) and H:2 (height). 
The new version adds the stroke measurement to this which makes it confusing. So if I have a 7pt thick stroke on a 4x2 box, it shows it as 4.0972x2.0972. All previous versions never added the stroke to the object size.
Can anyone tell me how to disable this feature? Or am I going to have to live with this?

Answer (score 1):

With Illustrator, check the stroke panel (<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>) and align stroke to inside.

[image]